# Oracle - one server with multiple databases, but separate hardware resources

Tags: oracle, configuration, hardware

I have one server (virtual machine) with Oracle on which I have 2 Oracle databases. During the peek periods both databases consumes hardware resources from each other and processing of data becomes very slow. For now there is no option to create next VM etc, so I'm thinking if in single Oracle database I can use i.e. up to 3 cores, 4GB RAM and specific partition (this I think can be easily done by putting data files to separate location). Do you know if I can configure single database like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look into Oracle resource manager , the will let you  control the amount of resource per oracle instance ( like Limiting I/O and CPU resources  per database  )

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/dbrm001.htm
http://askdba.org/weblog/2012/09/limiting-io-and-cpu-resources-using-11g-oracle-resource-manager/